# How do I import google API service (googleapis) into React js without nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, admin, google-apis-explorer, resolve

[**if i try to use the googleapis in reactjs**, *i obtain these error*.
**if i try to use the googleapis in reactjs**, *i obtain these error*.
**if i try to use the googleapis in reactjs**, *i obtain these error*.][1]

````
// configure a JWT auth client
let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
privatekey.client_email,
null,
privatekey.private_key,
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
//'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage'
],
"email",
);
//authenticate request
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
return;
} else {
console.log("Successfully connected!");
}
});

const admin = google.admin({
version: 'directory_v1',
auth: jwtClient
});

  admin.users.get({userKey}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error:', err.message);
    const user = res.data;
      console.log('Users:', user);
      return user;
    
  });```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKL4W.png
````

Comment: you don't, as [`googleapis`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) home page says, it is meant for nodejs only, you can't run it in browser. So implement api endpoints that make calls googleapis stuff in your backend, utilize it  in front end.